# I can not make the normal map bake in cycles

Tags: uv, baking

I can not make the normal map bake in the blender cycles 2.79 I already did the UV mapping right, I tried everything, the result is all rough as in the image below [image]

How can I fix this?

here is the .blender file
[image]

Comment: Hi, this is the way NORMALs should be bake... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r-cGjVKvGw ...hope it helps buddy.

Answer (score 0):

These "artifacts" are usually the result of a ZERO value in Ray Distance when bakeing, so try to change the value in a GREEN rectangle seen on the image below to a non-zero (0.1 or 0.05 should be fine).

[image]

Hope it helps André.

Comment: did not work, I changed the value of Ray distance to (0.05) and stayed the same geito

Comment: Hi, send the scene file please.

Comment: How can I send the .blender file to you Jan Matys, I'm new here?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not answering buddy, use this site to share it here bro... https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ...could be?

Comment: Hm, I saw the file but really dont understand what U baking on what (if normals)? Did U at least watch the video I sent U a link to bellow Yo question? Check it out ... gotta sleep

Comment: My friend, this is a blender bug 2.79?

Comment: Did U see the video buddy?

Comment: yes (blender guru)

Comment: And is that what You need or You wanna achieve something else?